Outlook Stuck on 'Processing...' While Sending Emails Between Primary and Delegate Accounts in MAPI C++ Plugin
We have developed an Outlook plugin in MAPI C++ that connects to our server and provides data to Outlook. The plugin has been functioning as expected.
However, I recently encountered an unusual issue. While sending an email from my primary account to my delegate account (mounted in the same profile with a persona created using SendAs rights), I noticed the following behavior:
Upon clicking the "Send/Receive All" button (F9), Outlook displays a "Processing..." message but does not complete the synchronization.
Emails sent from Outlook remain stuck in the outbox.
Despite this, the plugin appears to be functioning correctly. For instance, emails sent from the web client are received in Outlook without any issues.
Upon reviewing the Outlook log files (c:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\Opmlog.log), I noticed entries indicating that Outlook appears to be stuck during synchronization.
To resolve this, I attempted the following troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists:

Created a new profile: the same behavior occurs.
Disabled antivirus software: no improvement.
Disabled other unnecessary add-ins: no change.

Could anyone help identify the potential cause of this issue or suggest further steps to resolve it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated
Opmlog.log - Outlook log file when outlook stucks
2024.11.27 15:37:34 Starting the Spooling Cycle
2024.11.27 15:37:34 Starting the Simplified Transfer Cycle
2024.11.27 15:37:34 FINISHED MAPI TASK
2024.11.27 15:37:34 FINISHED MAPI TASK
2024.11.27 15:37:34 HELPER::Uninitialize called
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/--- -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 HELPER::Initialize called
2024.11.27 15:37:34 Initializing: Finding a Transport
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/--- -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/OUT -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 HELPER::Uninitialize called
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/--- -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 HELPER::Initialize called
2024.11.27 15:37:34 Initializing: Finding a Transport
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/--- -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/OUT -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 HELPER::Uninitialize called
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/--- -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 HELPER::Initialize called
2024.11.27 15:37:34 Initializing: Finding a Transport
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/--- -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/OUT -- ---)
2024.11.27 15:37:34 HELPER::Uninitialize called
2024.11.27 15:37:34 MAPI Status: (-- -- ---/--- -- ---)


Opmlog.log - Outlook log file when it works fine:
2024.11.27 15:54:54 Starting the Spooling Cycle
2024.11.27 15:54:54 MAPI XP Call: FlushQueues, hr = 0x00000000, ulFlushFlags = 0x0000001c
2024.11.27 15:54:54 Starting the Simplified Transfer Cycle
2024.11.27 15:54:54 Finishing the Spooling Cycle, Error code = 0x00000000
2024.11.27 15:54:54 FINISHED MAPI TASK
2024.11.27 15:54:54 Test: ReportStatus: RSF_COMPLETED, hr = 0x00000000

